# Software RAID Nonfunctional after power outage

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

My server lost power yesterday. It automatically booted up when power came back, but my RAID is now nonfunctional.

The RAID array is a software RAID6 built with mdadm. Originally, the array used 8 drives. Several months ago I noticed a drive failing SMART tests, so I replaced it. While replacing the drive, I added an additional 4 drives, which were originally in my previous server and formatted as ZFS (as a part of a FreeNAS RAIDZ), bringing the total drive count to 12.

Unfortunately I don't remember the exact command(s) I used to expand the array, and the command is no longer in my bash_history. I do not know why today mdadm is reporting 8 disks, and fdisk is reporting those 4 drives as being ZFS; I am confident that for the past several months I have been running a 12-disk RAID setup.

As far as I know, my server has not shut down or rebooted since replacing the bad drive and adding the 4 additional drives, until yesterday.

The only mdadm-related commands that I have run since the power loss are `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`, `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`, and `mdadm --assemble --scan -v`. I have not rebooted the server.

I realize that I need a backup and will implement one ASAP. For now, I'm just hoping there's a way to recover my data.

I'm running Debian 9 and mdadm 3.4.

I'm happy to provide any other information. (Please note that I don't consider myself a RAID or mdadm expert by any means.)

**Update:** I added the output of an mdadm examine for the "good"/"bad" drives. The "good" drives are correctly reporting raid6 and 12 drives.

## mdadm --detail /dev/md0

(Note: this was at boot, before running `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`. Also note that it reports raid0.)

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : blackcanary:0  (local to host blackcanary)
           UUID : 7bd22c29:465d927f:d0c1d08f:ba3694c9
         Events : 72036

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8      112        -        /dev/sdh
       -       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       -       8      128        -        /dev/sdi
       -       8       96        -        /dev/sdg
```

## fdisk -l

(Note: /dev/sdb and /dev/sdj are the only two drives that should NOT be in the array.)

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdg: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdh: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdi: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 57.9 GiB, 62109253632 bytes, 121307136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 764C7B0B-574D-40DF-95C0-06D765AEB2D2

Device        Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048   1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   1050624  54255615 53204992 25.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  54255616 121305087 67049472   32G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdj: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdk: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 41DFFB5A-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdk1      128    4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdk2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696  3.7T FreeBSD ZFS


Disk /dev/sdl: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 40C2CEAE-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdl1      128    4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdl2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696  3.7T FreeBSD ZFS


Disk /dev/sdm: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 402A1394-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdm1      128    4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdm2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696  3.7T FreeBSD ZFS


Disk /dev/sdn: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 415081DC-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdn1      128    4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdn2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696  3.7T FreeBSD ZFS
```

## blkid

```
/dev/sdd: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="91d8e433-aeb9-a4f2-75ca-10cf3ceb0a83" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sde: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="6ccd4cee-9fdd-872c-add0-209a9d074eb5" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="11bf8212-7c04-0c8c-a061-168bda9c34a5" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sda: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="6cee76b0-031c-bb6a-6c13-7d15d0b2feee" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdf: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="508cd116-e0ac-131c-cd0d-3c5c41c1cbba" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdg: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="0080d32e-7fea-037f-75a8-6e40dfa8fdfa" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdh: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="f1aa862e-6c4c-0239-5fb4-29d7a9dd7497" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdi: UUID="7bd22c29-465d-927f-d0c1-d08fba3694c9" UUID_SUB="32472d1f-25c1-dfb3-fa9a-57ab3df17986" LABEL="blackcanary:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="E15C-D029" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="dff9fca6-2eef-4084-845c-d780ca7b6cb8"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="bfd3d30c-de34-4e00-89b4-384bcbb7922d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7696f182-551e-447c-9549-155605cc48a3"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="7f65b504-ffe2-48e4-868f-a9db95865505" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="48ecdc7c-fb0a-404e-bc02-178063515b6c"
/dev/sdj: UUID="b59275af-0825-4f25-96d2-aff0c3fef5e5" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdk1: PARTUUID="41f3ae62-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdk2: LABEL="main" UUID="2939752790805872810" UUID_SUB="11544886583175140825" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="420ad019-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdl1: PARTUUID="40d655e5-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdl2: LABEL="main" UUID="2939752790805872810" UUID_SUB="15587016790013084755" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="40ef0474-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdm1: PARTUUID="403ea9c7-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdm2: LABEL="main" UUID="2939752790805872810" UUID_SUB="12390459856885165202" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="4057cbaa-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdn1: PARTUUID="416507e6-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
/dev/sdn2: LABEL="main" UUID="2939752790805872810" UUID_SUB="16896032374271545514" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="417ef281-7f8c-11e5-9d78-7824af43d5fa"
```

## mdadm --asemble --scan -v

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdn2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got b1f5ae15)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdn2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdn1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdn1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdn (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdn
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdm2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got fd87a884)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdm2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdm1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdm1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdm (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdm
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdl2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 946313cc)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdl2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdl1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdl1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdl (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdl
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdk2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 4de36623)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdk2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdk1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdk1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdk (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdk
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdj (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 0000043c)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb3 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb3
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000405)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdi is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 7.
mdadm: /dev/sdh is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 6.
mdadm: /dev/sdg is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdf is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sde is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sde to /dev/md0 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdf to /dev/md0 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/sdg to /dev/md0 as 5
mdadm: added /dev/sdh to /dev/md0 as 6
mdadm: added /dev/sdi to /dev/md0 as 7
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 8 of /dev/md0
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 9 of /dev/md0
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 10 of /dev/md0
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 11 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 8 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

## mdadm.conf

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Sun, 25 Jun 2017 22:28:24 -0500 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=blackcanary:0 UUID=7bd22c29:465d927f:d0c1d08f:ba3694c9
```

## mdadm --examine /dev/sdd

(Note: Very similar information returns for any of the "good" 8 drives)

```
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 7bd22c29:465d927f:d0c1d08f:ba3694c9
           Name : blackcanary:0  (local to host blackcanary)
  Creation Time : Sun Jun 25 22:53:12 2017
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 12

 Avail Dev Size : 7813780144 (3725.90 GiB 4000.66 GB)
     Array Size : 39068897280 (37259.00 GiB 40006.55 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813779456 (3725.90 GiB 4000.66 GB)
    Data Offset : 257024 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=256936 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 91d8e433:aeb9a4f2:75ca10cf:3ceb0a83

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Oct  7 14:23:36 2018
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b960e905 - correct
         Events : 72036

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

## mdadm --examine /dev/sdk

(Note: The same information returns for any of the "bad" 4 drives)

```
/dev/sdk:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

## fdisk -b 512 -t gpt -l /dev/sdn

```
Disk /dev/sdn: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 415081DC-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdn1      128    4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdn2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696  3.7T FreeBSD ZFS
```

## fdisk -b 4096 -t gpt -l /dev/sdn

```
Disk /dev/sdn: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 976754646 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 415081DC-7F8C-11E5-9D78-7824AF43D5FA

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdn1      128    4194431    4194304   16G FreeBSD swap
/dev/sdn2  4194432 7814037127 7809842696 29.1T FreeBSD ZFS
```

Comment: Check whether either `sudo fdisk -b 512 -t gpt -l /dev/sdn` or `sudo fdisk -b 4096 -t gpt -l /dev/sdn` shows the expected partitions.

Comment: I added the output of both of those to the original post. Some confusion on my end is that I wasn't expecting to see partitions for sd[k-n] considering the other drives don't list partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, I was able to restore my RAID array without apparent data loss.

I did ultimately have to use `mdadm --create --assume-clean`. I opted to use [overlay files](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file) so that I could non-destructively test various configurations until I found the correct one.

I used `mdadm --examine /dev/sd*` on the "good" drives to determine their order. Then, I generated the possible permutations of the "bad" drives and ran through them until I had a mountable filesystem. Luckily I only had 24 possible combinations to go through.

I ran through all 24 permutations and didn't have success mounting. I examined one of the mapper drives (`mdadm --examine /dev/mapper/sd*`) and compared it to the original and noticed that the data offset was different. I added the `data-offset` param to the config, re-tested the permutations, and had success after the 12th attempt.

These are the commands I ran while testing:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --create --assume-clean --run --level=6 --data-offset=128512 --raid-devices=12 /dev/md0 /dev/mapper/sdb /dev/mapper/sdc /dev/mapper/sda /dev/mapper/sdd /dev/mapper/sde /dev/mapper/sdf /dev/mapper/sdg /dev/mapper/sdh /dev/mapper/sdn /dev/mapper/sdm /dev/mapper/sdl /dev/mapper/sdk
dumpe2fs /dev/md0
fsck.ext4 -v /dev/md0
```

I used `dd` to backup the MBR and partition table of the "bad" drives, and then overwrote the MBR & partition table with zeroes to match the "good" drives, so that this shouldn't be an issue on future reboots.

After successfully rebuilding, I generated a new `mdadm.conf` file and recorded as much data as possible about the array in case I need it in the future. Now, I'm looking into a true backup solution.

Comment: ... have you also rebooted to confirm that your config holds?